# Javascript TypeError : i need explanation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript code

```
 Html5Template_300x250 = function(config) {
      this.config = config;
      var self = this;
      adkit.onReady(this.init());

  };
  Html5Template_300x250.prototype = {
      // Function That Creates Element Var
      d: function(id) {
          return document.getElementById(id);
      },

      // Initialize DCO HTML5 template
      init: function() {

          adkit.onReady(this.handleSVData);

      },
      handleSVData: function() {
          var myData = adkit.getSVData("varName");

          alert(myData);

          this.startAd();

      },

      startAd: function(data) {
          alert("test2");

      }
  }
```

In the above code i have used an external javascript adkit.js and using that method in my code. The initial method is started as

```
 adkit.onReady(this.init());
```

It is calling a init function and which is then calling other methods including handleSVData which is getting a value from the json file which is in the root folder as

```
var myData = adkit.getSVData("varName");
```

The part of the code is working fine but after that line i am calling another method

```
this.startAd();
```

But this method is not working and i am getting error

```
TypeError: this.startAd is not a function
```

I am not good in javascript and giving me headaches can someone explain me why it is so complicated and what i am doing wrong here ??

Comment: This doesn't look right `adkit.onReady(this.init())`. Then, what you want is `adkit.onReady(this.handleSVData.bind(this))`

Comment: well this part is working fine and it is under the specification to use the adkit like this to initialize the init method and adkit.getSVData to get values from the JSON file and this part is completely working fine but this.startAd() is not working

Comment: Learn about how `this` works: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback

Comment: Still, doesn't look right, because `onReady` expects a function I suppose, and `this.init` doesn't return a function, you probably want to pass a reference to it, not execute it.

Comment: this is how it is explain adkit.onReady(CallbackFunctionName);Waits for AdKit initialization and runs a callback function.

Comment: this.startAd(); works fine in other normal method but not in the handleSVData. This is because it goes out of the scope and then callback doesnot find this function?

Comment: @elclanrs - his `adkit.onReady(this.init());` is, of course, wrong, because `init` does not return anything. What matters is the `init()` call itself, that passes `this.handleSVData` to `adkit.onReady`. He could just call `this.init();` instead.

Comment: @lgor what do you mean . Can you explain me what i am doing wrong here?

Comment: Should it be adkit.onReady(this.init()); or adkit.onReady(this.init); without the brackets so that you are passing the function reference? In fact couldn't it be rewitten as adkit.onReady(this.handleSVData);?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `handleSVData` is called by `adkit` it is called in the scope that is not an instance of `Html5Template_300x250` - that is why `this` does not have `startAd` method.

As for `adkit.onReady(this.init());` line.

`adkit.onReady` expects a function as a parameter. It stores this function variable and calls when it is time for `onReady` event. This is set correctly by `adkit.onReady(this.handleSVData);` line. `this.init()`, however, is a call to `init` function and your line `adkit.onReady(this.init());` passes to `adkit.onReady` whatever `init` returns. But it does not return anything - you are passing `undefined` as parameter.

```
  init: function() {
      var template = this;
      adkit.onReady(function(){
        template.handleSVData();
      });
  },
```

And change line

```
adkit.onReady(this.init());
```

to

```
this.init();
```

Comment: then how to fix this what if i want to call startAd after that"

Comment: adkit.onReady(this.handleSVData.bind(this)) this has fixed everything but not sure how?

Comment: consider the `bind` method of a javascript function a short-hand notation of the `init` implementation that I showed: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind